# Syntax to define a custom service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

My service is working as expected in both cases but I don't understand the difference between these 2 syntaxes. Enlighten me please. The official documentation is not very explicit about this point.

Syntax A :

```
service.factory('Alert',['$rootScope', '$timeout', function($rootScope, $timeout) {
  //Do stuff
}]);
```

Syntax B :

```
service.factory('Alert', function($rootScope, $timeout) {
 //Do stuff 
});
```

Comment: Look at the [Dependency Injection (DI)](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) documentation. Especially the *Inline Annotation* subsection and *Where can I use DI?* section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They both provide the same functionality but `Syntax A` (inline bracket notation) allows for  your code to be minified through a JavaScript minifier. Because `Syntax A` is a little longer than `Syntax B` (and violates the DRY principle), the most appropriate and probably only case you'd want to use it would be when you want to minify your code.

> Since Angular infers the controller's dependencies from the names of
>   arguments to the controller's constructor function, if you were to
>   minify the JavaScript code for [the] PhoneListCtrl controller, all of its
>   function arguments would be minified as well, and the dependency
>   injector would not be able to identify services correctly.

[See this page for more information (*A Note on Minification*)](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05)

Answer (score 0):

I also found a third syntax in the documentation. It appears to be more proper than the "Syntax A" (array notation) and compatible with JavaScript minifier :

```
var service = angular.module('alertService', []);
var alertServiceFactory = function($rootScope, $timeout) {
 //Do stuff 
});
alertServiceFactory.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$timeout'];
service.factory('Alert', alertServiceFactory);
```

More info here : http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.managing_dependencies